# RadioButton style that crash ( ? )

Tags: silverlight

I wrote RadioButton style - and the code crash and i don't find any reason to having this crash.

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle2" TargetType="RadioButton">

    <Setter Property="Foreground"                   Value="#5DFFC8" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">

                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>

                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonStyle2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>

                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonStyle2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" To="Black" />

                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
```

Comment: This is only part of the style. Post it all and please be as specific as possible: what crashes? What is the exception? Are you sure it is the template?

Comment: this is the part that make the crash. when i remark this part all work with no crash

Comment: When you remove this code from your solution it will not compile. Please post all of the style code.

Comment: yes - its compile ... and the rest of the code is just closing the xaml style ( .. \> )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the first block of code in this answer tries to repeat the problem:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle2"
               TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#5DFFC8" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonPart"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="1" />

                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonPart"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                            To="Black" />

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonPart" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle2}" IsChecked="True">Test</RadioButton>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If the shown code is all there is, there is a lot missing.

I pasted the code I used to test your style here and added some. Have a look at the exception in the designer it will probably look like this:

[image: Exception information]

This should tell you what is wrong. In my code there is a mismatch between the type of the Foreground property (Brush) and the animation (Color).

You will can make them match by animating the color property of the brush (SolidBrush)

Below is a better working sample (still not complete but the animations work)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle2"
               TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#5DFFC8" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonPart"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="1" />

                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="radioButtonForegroundColor"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                            To="Black" />

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonPart"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             To="0.5" />

                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="radioButtonForegroundColor"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                            To="Red" />

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonPart"
                                         IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
                                         Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <RadioButton.Foreground>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"
                                                     x:Name="radioButtonForegroundColor" />
                                </RadioButton.Foreground>
                            </RadioButton>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle2}"
                         Content="Test 1" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle2}"
                         IsChecked="False"
                         Content="Test 2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is

```
Storyboard.TargetName="RadioButtonStyle2"
```

*RadioButtonStyle2* is the name of this Style. The TargetName should be the name of one of the controls you defined inside your ControlTemplate.

When you are trying to check a RadioButton with this style it will give you an error. If you use Expression Blend, go to the Checked state within this style, it will throw you an error saying,
*An animation is trying to modify an object named 'RadioButtonStyle2', but no such object can be found in the Grid.*

I see you are trying to change the Opacity and the Foreground color when this RadioButton is checked. To do this, you need to add a ContentControl inside the Grid. And change the Opacity of the Grid and the Foreground color of this ContentControl in the Checked visual state, not the style itself.

Hope this helps.